# How to implement a SOAP client in C# (specifically for Windows Mobile)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, soap, compact-framework

I'm really confused about how to create a SOAP client in C# using .NET. I have found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819935.aspx) which looks really promising, but for the life of me I can't find Microsoft.Web.Services2. Also most information I find about SOAP with C#/.NET are about creating web services in ASP.NET and that's not what I want to do.

Basically what I want to do is implement a SOAP client in C# in a Windows Mobile application.

Comment: I found another way to implement a SOAP client, which was to just right-click the project and select "Add web reference". I entered my WSDL URI and it automatically generated classes for the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Download the old [OpenNETCF.Web.Services2 source code](http://opennetcf.com/CompactFramework/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) (in the deprecated source downloads at the bottom of the page).  Depending on your exact needs, this will probably provide the WSE classes you need.